Python reading file in VSCode
I'm looking to read a file in Python through VSCode. I'd searched some helps in old post on Stackoverflow but nothing.
This is my code:
1)
file = open("prova.txt", "r")
content = file.read()
print(content)
file.close()




with open("prova.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    file = f.read()
    print(file)

Both examples return empty string.
I'm looking to read the file in Python

the code seems fine, also if not existed, there would be error. Can you confirm that txt file has some text or anything in it?? if yes, try testing by using "rb" instead of "r"

Aside: I would explicitly add the "r" into your second implementation; it's more readable that way.

@RatulHasan Nothing still! return b" but no the text inside the file

since there is no error and the return is empty, then the file is empty. If there were something it would show up

use print(os.path.realpath("prova.txt")) to check if its reading the right file (returns file directory)
